# Customize inbulid navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can  I change the colour of  Hamburger​ button of a navigation drawble of inbulid Android studio navigation activity.?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom icon:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                yourCustomIcon, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```